# Erlang timer counter (timer:tc) rounding to nearest 1000?

Tags: timer, parallel-processing, erlang

I am trying to time how long an execution takes. (I'm comparing times of an execution depending of the number of processes spawned.) Anyways, timer:tc is returning times rounded to the nearest 1000 ms. I have seen people have better accuracy than that and I am wondering what could cause this?

Comment: Can you show a code sample of how it is being used? I get microsecond results from it. Perhaps everything is executing 1000 times faster than you think? (Beware that tc/3 executes dynamically using apply/3 and can sometimes give longer results than tc/1 or tc/2 because of this -- but that's not anything close to 1000 times delay.)

Answer (score 2):

This is the case on Windows OS (at least XP and 7), but it is rounded to 1000µs, not ms.

Except with very short function it is not a big problem since the execution time varies from one execution to the other.

Answer (score 2):

Erlang rounds down to 1ms on Windows.
A common way to work around this is to run your code many times (let's say 1000) and then to divide the time you get by 1000. This will give you a more accurate mean result.